# how to use socket.io-client-swift properly

Tags: ios, swift, socket.io

I search through the internet for a proper example for the use of `Socket.IO` on iOS (actually th client side - `socket.io-client-swift`) with clear coding examples. anyone can help me out with this.

Comment: This will help: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift

Comment: Here is the tutorial that makes a chat app using sicket.io: https://www.appcoda.com/socket-io-chat-app/

Comment: Thanks @FaysalAhmed

Answer (score 1):

here an example of socket io client.

```
import SocketIO    
class soket {
    var lat = ""
    var lng = ""
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as!AppDelegate
    init(lat: String, lng: String) {
        self.lat = lat
        self.lng = lng
    }
    func connect()  {
        print("llamada al socket")
        print(contantes.init().addres)
        let socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: URL(string: contantes.init().addres)!,config: [.connectParams(["accessToken" : appDelegate.token]),.forcePolling(true),.nsp("/vendedor"), .log(true)])
        let myJSON = [
            "lng":lng,
            "lat":lat,
            "idvendedor":appDelegate.idSeller
        ]
        socket.on("connect") {data, ack in
            print("socket connected")
            socket.emit("setLocation",myJSON)
            print("Mostrando el Json: \(myJSON)")
        }
        socket.on("locationChanged", callback: {_,_ in
            print("disconnected")
            socket.disconnect()
        })
        socket.connect()
    }
}
```

this class is a simple socket to report device location to a server side, in this case the server side use namespace so the socket must join it so send data. here is th code how is called in viewController

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if let location = locations.first {
        let sok = soket(lat: String(location.coordinate.latitude),lng:String(location.coordinate.longitude))
        sok.connect()
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
}
```

the main concepts behind sockets is that configure handlers to listen or emit data from server and the make the connection. 
here another example [Socket.IO client integration in iOS Swift](http://www.vishalvirodhia.com/socket-io-client-integration-in-ios-swift.html#respond)

Comment: thank you. could you please explain the parameters in this line.'let socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: URL(string: contantes.init().addres)!,config: [.connectParams(["accessToken" : appDelegate.token]),.forcePolling(true),.nsp("/vendedor"), .log(true)])
        '

Comment: this params are specific for mi backend to connet but  a url for the backend in soketURL and config is an array with things needed in backend in this case the accesstoken, force polling is to enable websokect, nsp is to join a namespace in case needed, and log is to show logs in xcode..